# Photoshop scripting: selectedFile.open("r") is not a function?

Tags: photoshop-script

Just trying to read a CSV, as indicated in this post:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/read-a-txt-file/m-p/3781245

But keep getting that error, why?

[image]

```
var prompt = "Elegir cuadro de materiales"
var filter = "*";
var multi_select = true;


var selectedFile = File.openDialog(["Elegir cuadro de materiales"], filter, multi_select);

alert(selectedFile);


selectedFile.open('r');

var dataToGet = selectedFile.readln();

selectedFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Results that `openDialog` with `multiSelect` set to true, returns an array.

So, this solves the issue:

```
var prompt = "Elegir cuadro de materiales"
var filter = "*";
var multi_select = true;


var selectedFile = File.openDialog(["Elegir cuadro de materiales"], filter, multi_select);

alert(selectedFile);


selectedFile[0].open('r');

var dataToGet = selectedFile[0].readln();

selectedFile[0].close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've solved your own problem, another way to do it is with a new File

```
selectedFile = File.openDialog("Elegir cuadro de materiales","File:*.TXT", true);
var myFile = new File(selectedFile[0]); //first in array
myFile.open('r');
// read the file here
myFile.close();
```